# MessageBoxButton.YesNo error when press NO

Tags: c#

When I press Disconnect button in form, is asking me if Yes or No. I press No, but then I can do only one action in program because after that, it crashes. Why?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialres = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca vreti sa va deconectati?",
      "Atentie!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialres == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       try
       {
          _conn.Close();
          _conn = null;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          return;
       }

       button1.Enabled = true;
       stopbut();
    }
    else if (dialres == DialogResult.No) 
    { 
       return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean? What's the error?

Comment: Don't you have to show us the code that is crashing?

Comment: `(dialres == DialogResult.OK)` should be `DialogResult.Yes`.

Comment: I am not sure to have read correctly your comment to an answer below. You press the NO button and the program crashes. But you don't show the entire code of the NO branch? Are you making a quiz  to check if we are able to guess the reason?

Comment: No, I think something is missing from the code but do not know exactly what,that's why I called you.

Answer (score -1):

Your first `if` will never be true, because you are testing for OK, not for YES. In your second `if` you have a return statement, so your method will finish. So not really sure what else you expected?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP didn't provide the code that is causing the program to "crash" so you couldn't possibly know.

Comment: It certainly solves one problem he is having - though he maybe didn't realize it yet.

Comment: It should be a comment. You even mention in your answer that you aren't sure what OP expected.

Answer (score -2):

when you press 'No' nothing change so there should be another reason for crash, maybe that one action you do cause the crash. when you do any action your program crash or a specific one?

Edit: put the code of action that cause the crash

sorry everyone, i should comment not answer :( but i cant comment because commenting needs 50 reputations and i have only 39

and your code maybe more efficient like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialres =;

    if ( MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca vreti sa va deconectati?",
      "Atentie!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No) return;
    //when it ain't 'No' it is definitely 'Yes'  
    try
    {
       _conn.Close();
       _conn = null;
     }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          return;
       }

       button1.Enabled = true;
       stopbut();
    }
    else if (dialres == DialogResult.No) 
    { 
       return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a question, please ask it in the comments section, not as an answer.

Comment: No, program works perfectly. I don't receive any error as a message, is just not the entire code for No button, I guess..

Comment: sorry, i wanted to add extra